# About locus in general

Tags: geometry, locus

Assume that we want to find the locus of a point. If we prove that three different positions of this point are collinear, then can we say that the locus is the line connecting these positions?

Comment: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=130220

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your locus is an non-reducable algebraic curve of degree $d$, then it will intersect a line at up to $d$ points. So if $d\geq3$ (e.g. $d=3$, a [cubic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_plane_curve)), then you can expect to find three collinear points, although the curve is not a line.